# How to verify a password without sending it unencrypted to a server

Tags: java, authentication, hash, server, bcrypt

I want to build a **login application**, that has a client for username and password input, as well as a server, which then recieves the username and the password.

The server should then check, wheather the password it recieved matches the already stored hash, or not.
I thought it would be smart not to send the password unencrypted (just in a String) from the client to the server, so I already encrypted it on the client side with BCrypt.

But now i have two hashes on the server-side, but BCrypt only offers the methode to **compare** a plaintext with a hash, not **a hash with a hash**.

Should I now send the password in plaintext to the server or is there a way to compare two hashes?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use TLS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: And then just send the password in plain text?

Comment: It's not plaintext if it's sent via TLS

Answer (score 2):

"Challenge-Response" is the term you should google for.

The Principle:

On server side you have stored a hashed (salted) password and the salt.

The client sends first the login name.

The server looks up the salt of the login in the database and sends this to the client, together with a random string (That's the Challenge).

The Client has now to calculate an encrypted password in the following way: Concatenate login password with salt and hash it. Concatenate the result with the random string from the challenge and hash it. Send the result to the server.

The server now concatenates the hashed password (stored in user database) with the random string sent together with the Challenge and calculates the hash. The result must be exactly the same as the result recieved from the client.

Comment: Had to sketch it first, but thanks for the good explanation. A simpler way than using the tls-protocol, which i have to take a look at too.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch hashed value from database and compare it with sent value

Comment: What exactly do you mean?